# Forgot what did i do with python script run on start up

Tags: raspbian

i will be fast, i made a `python script` to be run on boot on raspberry pi, but i forgot how did i do it, i checked everything and i cannot find what is making the script run, is there any workaround to check, plus i can see 3 processes running  of that same script and its making a mess, i tried crontab, systemd, rc.local, but i cannot find where i am running it from.
I also went through all the tutorials to try and remember how i did it but with no luck
Thank you

Comment: There must be thousands of posts / instructions / tutorials about this on the Internet... What exactly have you done so far to solve your problem? Also show us what the exact problem is (error msgs etc). And make sure you add plenty of details.

Comment: Hello , i found the scrpt it was in nodm script ,FINNALLY, but i sill cant figure out why is see 3 processes of the same script ,my question was , is there a way to find the path of the process buy the PID number ?

Comment: Well, that's definitely not a Pi-specific problem...

Comment: your question should be in the post at the top, not buried in a comment